# Homestead - accessing via http://localhost:PORT

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

Does anyone know if there is a way to resolve `http://localhost:PORT` to a project that is running on homestead.
so traditionally you could just set up your desired address on `host` and `Homestead.yaml` as follow.

**host**

```
192.168.10.10 first.test
192.168.10.10 second.test
```

**Homestead.yaml**

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
folders:
    ## first config
    - map: C:\Users\first
      to: /home/vagrant/first
    ## first config
    - map: C:\Users\second
      to: /home/vagrant/second
sites:
    ## first config
    - map: first.test
      to: /home/vagrant/first/public
      php: "7.1"    
    ## second config
    - map: second.test
      to: /home/vagrant/second/public
      php: "7.1"
```

but when I want to use `localhost:8082` or `localhost:8083` instead of `first.test` and `second.test` It does't work.

**side note**: the reason I want to use localhost is because I have multiple projects and I'm working on [laravel webpush](https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/webpush) and Service Workers requires HTTPS unless you are using localhost.

thanks

Comment: It is option that should be set on web server software to be listened: [apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html), [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/#wildcard-subdomains-in-a-parent-folder) (pay attention on port parts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable https on homestead instead.

[Windows](https://medium.com/dinssa/ssl-certificates-laravel-homestead-windows-https-f83ec8b3198)
[Mac](https://www.eaglepeakweb.com/blog/how-to-enable-ssl-https-tls-laravel-homestead)

Answer (score 0):

For others who might want to know, while trying the `localhost:PORT` approach failed multiple times. I decided to take a different path and enable https on homestead instead. simply following [Homestead SSL on Windows](https://medium.com/dinssa/ssl-certificates-laravel-homestead-windows-https-f83ec8b3198) or [Homestead SSL on Mac](https://www.eaglepeakweb.com/blog/how-to-enable-ssl-https-tls-laravel-homestead).